# Unexpected "Tachyon file system can not be instantiated" for an HDFS checkpoint directory

Tags: apache-spark, persistence

For a spark program that has been running and executed dozens of times suddenly there is an interesting file system error occurring on the following logic to set the `checkpoint dir` :

```
val tempDir = s"alsTest"
sc.setCheckpointDir(tempDir)
```

Here is the error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider tachyon.hadoop.TFS could not be instantiated
```

Here is full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider tachyon.hadoop.TFS could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setCheckpointDir$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2076)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setCheckpointDir$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setCheckpointDir(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at com.blazedb.spark.ml.AlsTest$.main(AlsTest.scala:331)
    at com.blazedb.spark.ml.AlsTest.main(AlsTest.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tachyon.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:328)
    at tachyon.hadoop.AbstractTFS.<clinit>(AbstractTFS.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied (connect failed)
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.getLocalIpAddress(NetworkAddressUtils.java:398)
    at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.getLocalHostName(NetworkAddressUtils.java:320)
    at tachyon.conf.TachyonConf.<init>(TachyonConf.java:122)
    at tachyon.conf.TachyonConf.<init>(TachyonConf.java:111)
    at tachyon.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied (connect failed)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable0(Native Method)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable(Inet6AddressImpl.java:77)
    at java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:502)
    at java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:461)
    at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.isValidAddress(NetworkAddressUtils.java:414)
    at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.getLocalIpAddress(NetworkAddressUtils.java:382)
    ... 33 more
```

Note that using the relative path of `alsTest` had been working fine before. Our RDD storage is set to `MEMORY_AND_SER`  (*not* `OFF_HEAP`). We can also verify that by viewing the contents in the `hdfs`:

```
$hdfs dfs -lsr
drwxr-xr-x   - boescst supergroup          0 2016-12-13 12:43 alsTest/78081dc9-06f5-43d6-bcfb-1cfea7b4f015
drwxr-xr-x   - boescst supergroup          0 2016-12-13 12:19 alsTest/e2dd272b-19fe-4ee8-87d0-2a9afe141c9e
```

So why would the Spark FileSystem class now try to access `OFF_HEAP` (tachyon) ?

**Update** This is becoming more interesting: even explicitly specifying `hdfs` URL results in the Tachyon error

```
val tempDir = s"hdfs://$host:8020:alsTest/"
sc.setCheckpointDir(tempDir)

<same error as above>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with new ***VPN*** software that was first enabled yesterday on my system  When the VPN software were suspended then the `HDFS` url is properly resolved again.